# If p is an odd prime, show that $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> If p is an odd prime, show that $p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8 $.

I know that odd numbers are of the form $2k \pm 1$. Then $p^2=(2k \pm 1)^2= 4k^2 \pm 4k +1$. But it does not help to solve.

Comment: It works for any odd number:

$(4k\pm 1)^2=16k^2\pm 8k+1$

Comment: @user26486 odds are of the form $2k \pm 1$. Then $p^2=(2k \pm 1)^2= 4k^2 \pm 4k +1$. But it does not help to solve.

Comment: Odds are of the form $2k+1$, but they're also always either of the form $4m+1$ or $4m-1$; i.e. they're always of the form $4m\pm 1$. Then $(4m\pm 1)^2=16m^2\pm 8m+1$.

Comment: Hint: $\ k\,$ or $\,k\pm1\,$ is even so $\,8\mid 4k(k\pm 1) = 4k^2\pm 4k. \  $ You don't need the $\pm$ sign since e.g.  $\ 2k-1 = 2(k\!-\!1)+1.\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  prime doesn't matter. Just try all the cases.